# iMac 2013 Catalina, stuck on partitioning

Tags: bootcamp

Ive looked through countless forums and coding and hours of support from Apple both through forums and phone, yet have found no solution to the simple issue I'm facing. When clicking Install when prompted to partition the disk, the download seems to be unresponsive for hours.

Comment: What seems non-responsive?  The partitioning or the downloading?

Comment: It gets stuck on the partitioning

Comment: "disk partitioning: system may be unresponsive, yadah yadah"

Comment: You may have a failing hard drive.  Use  [DiskDrill](https://www.cleverfiles.com/) to run drive diagnostics - it's free (they charge for data recovery).  There's a SMART report that you can run.  Post those results.

Comment: I dont see a general: smart report, button

Comment: It's part of the "Extra Free Tools"  see home page.  As for a button - I don't know what you're seeing so I can't direct you.

Comment: i dont see an "extra free tools" on their homepage either

Comment: i thought your link wouldve lead directly to the smart report thing

Comment: It's the second section in blue.  I did link to it.  You have to scroll just a little bit.

Comment: can you describe the link i should click

Comment: Restore Data on Any Internal or External Storage, iOS and Android; Extra Free Disk Tools; Top Use Cases for Mac Data Recovery.

Comment: I believe i figured it out, the light is green indicating its fine